# Signed APK Proguard error Duplicate zip entry okio-1.6.0.jar:okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class

Tags: android, android-proguard, okio

I know this question asked previously but i got an error for generating signed apk file after setting **minifyEnabled=true**
Following is the message display in console

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write
 [E:\andriod_app_v2\app
 \build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] 
 (Can't read [C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\
 caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.6.0\98476622f10715998eacf9240d6b479f12c66143\okio-1.6.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
 (Duplicate zip entry [f/a$1.class == okio-1.6.0.jar:okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class]))
```

I searched on stackoverflow but i did not get any proper solution can somebody please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

use this in file proguard-rules.pro

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### -- OkHttp --
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**

#### -- Apache Commons --
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**


-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.**

##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn okio.**
```